# automatic detection/conversion of data types?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a function in numpy that determines whether strings should be integers or floating point numbers and automatically converts them? For instance, I often have a collection of records which are parsed from a text file using a combination of `str.strip()` and `str.split()`. Then I get something like

```
List = [['1','a','.3'],
        ['2','b','-.5']]
```

Which is then converted using `numpy.rec.fromrecords`:

```
In [1227]: numpy.rec.fromrecords(List)
Out[1227]: 
rec.array([('1', 'a', '.3'), ('2', 'b', '-.5')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '|S1'), ('f1', '|S1'), ('f2', '|S3')])
```

In R, there is a function called `type.convert` to which vectors/columns of character strings are passed and it will determine what the type for the column should be (i.e. if it's a mix of strings and numbers it will remain a character vector). Excel does this also (based on its first 6 elements, if I recall correctly)...

Is there such a function in NumPy/Python? I know I could probably write a function to test whether each element of a column could be converted to an integer, etc., but is there anything built in?  I know in all the examples the prescription is to specify the dtypes explicitly, but I would like to skip this step. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824862/data-type-recognition-guessing-of-csv-data-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt) can guess dtypes if you set `dtype=None`:

```
import numpy as np
import io

alist = [['1','a','.3'],
        ['2','b','-.5']]

f = io.BytesIO('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in alist))
arr = np.genfromtxt(f,dtype=None)
print(arr)
print(arr.dtype)
# [(1, 'a', 0.3) (2, 'b', -0.5)]
# [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '|S1'), ('f2', '<f8')]
```

Note that it would be better to apply `np.genfromtxt` directly to your text file instead of creating the intermediate list `List` (or what I called `alist`). If you need to do some processing of the file before sending it to `np.genfromtxt`, you could make a [file-like object wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923214/create-numpy-array-from-matrix-declared-inside-m-matlab-file/7923287#7923287) around the file which can do the processing and be passed to `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: That's a very interesting solution! Seems a bit indirect... but maybe this is still the best way...

Comment: Actually the object-wrapper concept is quite helpful, as with the `io.BytesIO` trick. I looked at the source code to extract the part which does the conversion but it seems like it is not so straightforward as it is not its own modular component within `np.genfromtxt`. This seems best.