# Cast list of string to different data type in python

Tags: python, split, casting

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to parse the following string:

```
line = "NOVEL_SERIES, 3256432, 8, 1, 2.364, 4.5404, 9.8341"
key, id, xval, yval, est1, est2, est3 = line.split()
id   = int(id)
xval = int(value1)
yval = int(value2)
est1 = float(est1)
est2 = float(est2)
est3 = float(est3)
```

Comment: what is your goal exactly?

Comment: I think you mean `line.split(", ")` ?

Comment: Also you probably mean `xval = int(xval)` and `yval = int(yval)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a bit more readable by expliciting converters :

```
In [29]: types=[str,int,int,int,float,float]

In [30]: [f(x) for (f,x) in zip(types,line.split(', '))]
Out[30]: ['NOVEL_SERIES', 3256432, 8, 1, 2.364, 4.5404]
```

Comment: Wow...that's a really interesting approach. Good job!

Comment: I have a question, since I am new to Python and just try to understand: why both x('10.9') and float('10.9') return the same value?

>>> x
<type 'float'>
>>> x('10.9')
10.9
>>> float(10.9)
10.9

Comment: I don't understand whats is x here ?

Comment: B.M. please see the better format question I just added bellow

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt) to automatically detect data types (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020296/771848)) - specify the `dtype` as `None` and set the appropriate delimiter:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>>
>>> buffer = StringIO(line)
>>> key, id, xval, yval, est1, est2, est3 = np.genfromtxt(buffer, dtype=None, delimiter=", ").tolist()
>>> key
'NOVEL_SERIES'
>>> id
3256432
>>> xval
8
>>> yval
1
>>> est1
2.364
>>> est2
4.5404
>>> est3
9.8341
```

Comment: @idjaw definitely, same here, but we should always remember that "explicit is better than implicit" too.

Answer (score 0):

you can build on B.M. s answer to get ALL the fields and name them:

```
line = "NOVEL_SERIES, 3256432, 8, 1, 2.364, 4.5404, 9.8341"
types=[str,int,int,int,float,float,float]
key, id, xval, yval, est1, est2, est3 = [f(x) for (f,x) in zip(types,line.split(', '))]

>>> [key, id, xval, yval, est1, est2, est3]
['NOVEL_SERIES', 3256432, 8, 1, 2.364, 4.5404, 9.8341]
>>> key
'NOVEL_SERIES'
```